# Classification SVM

Tags: matlab, signal-analysis, mfcc

I have a problem with Support Vector Machine classification.

I have two classes of children (boys and girls). I use a MFCC function for training (for each class I have 24 coefficients, number of frames ).

I have to create a test text file for testing my Libsvm classification, but I don't know how to reduce the MFCC matrices to a single vector.

Below is my source code with my attempt.

Any help is appreciated.

```
 class(1).list=['M01';'M02';'M03';'M04';'M05';'M06';'M07';'M08';'M09';'M10';'M11';'M12'];
      class(2).list=['W01';'W02';'W03';'W04';'W05';'W06';'W07';'W08';'W09';'W10';'W11';'W12'];
     repertoire='./data/Pure/';
          frame = 1024;
        hamwin=hamming(frame); 
             X1 =[];
            X2 =[];

                 disp('Phase d apprentissage')

            X2=[];
           %calclul des coefficients mfcc 
           k=1;
          for l=1:2
        numer=class(k).list(l,: );
            nomfichier=[repertoire numer]
          [y,fs] = wavread(nomfichier);
         for i=1:frame:length(y)-frame % 50%

           s=y(i:i+frame-1).*hamwin;
          rand('state',1);
           X1= mfcc(y,fs,24);
         X2=[X2 X1];
            fid = fopen('APPRE.txt','w');
             fprintf (fid,'1 %i\t %i\t %i\t %i\t %i\t %i\t %i\t %i\t %i\t %i\t %i\t %i\n',X2');
    end
```

Comment: You can reshape a matrix `A` into a vector using the syntax `A(:)`. Btw. if you use libsvm from Matlab, I recommend you use the Matlab interface to libsvm (contained in their distribution), this way you don't have to write a text file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i didn't understand how to use Matlab interface ,there is a command ?? because libsvmread                  [label_vector, instance_matrix] = libsvmread('filename');
 should read from a file wich contain labels and features and in my case features are matrix

Comment: As I wrote, for the [Matlab interface](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/#matlab) you don't need to write files. It provides mex-files `svmtrain` and `svmpredict` that you can directly call from Matlab. See https://github.com/cjlin1/libsvm/blob/master/matlab/README